# how to determine whether a value stored in session has expired in php?

Tags: php

I stored a variable in the session storage in php, how should I determine whether the value stored in session has expired?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched PHP documentation before asking the question?

Comment: just try to access that value

Comment: What do you mean by stored value expiration? Do you mean the expiration of the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try isset().
if I have a session named a, so you can use isset($_SESSION["a"])
it will return false if your session has expired